CORS: How to config actix-web allow multiple domains
I need two web sites, domain1.com and domain2.com, to access the API.
This is the API CORS config:
return HttpResponse::Ok()
    .insert_header(header::ContentType::json())
    .insert_header((header::ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, "https://domain1.com, https://domain2.com"))
    .json(result);

But as result, none of the two web sites could access the API.
If i just put one, then could access from the site.
return HttpResponse::Ok()
    .insert_header(header::ContentType::json())
    .insert_header((header::ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, "https://domain1.com"))
    .json(result);

But I need two or more domains to be able to access that API.

You can use the actix_cors crate to help you handle the CORS middleware.
use actix_cors::Cors;
let cors = Cors::default()
        .allow_any_origin()
        .allow_any_method()
        .allow_any_header()
        .expose_any_header()
        .max_age(36000);

And add cors into actix_web server's middleware.

Thanks Nickniki for your comments, then how to allow multiple specific domains?

@xlx You can use allowed_origin_fn to write you own rules about which domains are allowed.
